# Wordpress WP_Query get next post with same category

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I'm trying to get the next post with the same category as the current post in WP. I'm not trying to get the link of the next post (`next_post_link()`) but the post itself.

Currently I'm only getting the latest post with the same category, that is not the post itself.

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => $maincat_slug, 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID )) );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) : 
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); 
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'teaser' ); 
    endwhile;
endif;
```

`$maincat_slug`includes the (first) category slug of the current post (`get_the_category()`).

Maybe we can alter `'post__not_in'`to include the current and all previous posts?

EDIT:

`get_next_post_link` has no category filter, so this won't work here I think.

Or we can use `offset` to start after the current post. Not sure how to calculate the index of the current post within the loop though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I pulled it off using the wp_query `offset`

1. Run the loop for the first time to check the Index of the current post in the loop
2. Set the offset for the second loop to the index of the current page (+1)
3. Run the second loop with the offset from the first loop.

This way the second loop ignores all posts that came before the current post and displays the first post that comes after the current.

Code:

```
// Get current category (first cat if multiple are set)
$category = get_the_category(); 
$maincat_slug = $category[0]->slug;

// Get current Post ID
$current_id = $post->ID; 

// Reset offset
$offset = 0;

// Calculate offset
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => $maincat_slug ) );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) : 
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : 
        $query->the_post(); 
        $test_id = $post->ID;
        if ( $test_id == $current_id ) :
            // Set offset to current post
            $offset = $query->current_post + 1;
        endif;
    endwhile; 
endif;

// Display next post in category
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => $maincat_slug, 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'offset' => $offset) );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) : 
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : 
        $query->the_post(); 
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'teaser' ); 
    endwhile; 
else :
    // Fallback 
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `url_to_postid()` to retrieve the id from the link, then fetch the post:

```
$link = next_post_link();
$postid = url_to_postid( $link );

$query = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => $maincat_slug, 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'p' => $postid );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) : 
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); 
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'teaser' ); 
    endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: Nice method, I got a similar result with `'post__not_in' => range(0,$post->ID))`. Sadly a wrong post (the current) was shown. Maybe the problem is my Intuitive Custom Post Type Order plugin?

Comment: The plugin was part of the problem. But still... this is not working. First of all it has to be `get_next_post_link()` instead of `next_post_link()`. But this won't work either because: We get the ID of the next post. But if this next post dosn't have the class `$maincut_slug` the query won't have any results. right?

Comment: Right so the query should be done just against p=postID

Comment: Yes, but `get_next_posts_link`hast no category-filter (not sure why!). So this will get the next post link regardless of it's category. `next-post-link`has a category filter... but this dosn't help. Thanks for your help anyway!